# Heroku build fails at npm install stage because of a deleted local package

Tags: git, heroku, npm

I can run the app locally, but the Heroku build log gives

```
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       npm ERR! path /tmp/build_f006003c37b56af35aede303d1931e45/node_modules/@domain/endpoints
       npm ERR! code ENOENT
       npm ERR! errno -2
       npm ERR! syscall access
       npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, access '/tmp/build_f006003c37b56af35aede303d1931e45/node_modules/@domain/endpoints'
       npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
       npm ERR! enoent 

       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.iEXJN/_logs/2019-09-25T14_25_49_996Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
```

As you can see, it's complaining that '@domain/endpoints' does not exist. But I removed every reference to '@domain/endpoints'. So why is this happening?

The deploy works via a pipeline from the development branch on our BitBucket repository to Heroku. I've checked that the development branch contains no references to '@domain/endpoints'.

The "@domain" module contains packages that we created ourselves.

My package.json file can be found here: https://pastebin.com/mB7LcvBH I changed the name at the top, hope that doesn't cause any inconsistencies elsewhere.

Comment: can you show the package.json file?

Comment: @karthikdivi done :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was to clear the build cache.

See https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache

```
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
$ heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname
$ git commit --allow-empty -m "Purge cache"
$ git push heroku master
```